# data and salt arguments required - Swagger

Tags: node.js, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I am using Swagger UI to send post request in order to register users to the mongoDB.  I am getting the following error

- on the backend terminal: data and salt arguments required
- On the UI console: POST http://localhost:3002/register net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

My app is already using CORS:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:5173', 'http://localhost:3002'],
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "UPDATE", "DELETE", "PUT" , "PATCH"],
    credentials: true
}))
```

My code for the registration (including swagger) is as follow:

```
/**
 * @swagger
 *  tags:
 *   name: Employee Model
 *   description: api to manage employees Model
 */
/**
 * @swagger
 *   components:
 *     schemas:
 *       EmployeeModel:
 *         type: object
 *         properties:
 *           name:
 *             type: string
 *           email:
 *             type: string
 *           password:
 *             type: string
 */
/**
 * @swagger
 *   /register: 
 *     post:
 *       summary: This api is used to register new employee
 *       tags: [Employee Model]
 *       description: This api is used to register new employee
 *       requestBody:
 *         required: true
 *         content:
 *           application/json:
 *             schema:
 *               type: array
 *               items:
 *                 $ref: '#/components/schemas/EmployeeModel'
 *       responses:
 *         200:
 *           description: This api is used to post data to mongodb (register employee)
 */
// Addiong single user to the databse  (to Mongo - document)
// Register Users for login
app.post('/register', (req, red) => {
    const {name, email, password} = req.body
    bcrypt.hash(password, 10)
    .then(hash => {
        EmployeeModel.create({name, email, password: hash})
        .then(employee => res.json(employee))
        .catch(err => red.json(err))
    }).catch(err => console.log(err.message))
})
```

Is there something wrong on my code ? Any advices how to improve the code to successfully insert the data ?